# What does a gasoline fuel contain

Tags: hydrocarbons

I would like to ask you a quetsion about hydrocarbons and gasoline. If you mix a octane with ethanol, what kind of bonds would you gate as in how  will the atoms react. Can you in someway explain it as polar and nonpolar bond. I would so appriciate any answer.

Comment: If you mix ethanol and  octane, you'll get a mixture; there is no chemical reaction.

Comment: And just to be clear about the common misunderstanding: gasoline fuel doesn't contain much octane.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting so many downvotes. Seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

The most common [constituents of gasoline](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxprofiles/tp72-c3.pdf) are branched alkanes (25-40%), mostly having 5 or 6 carbons, and aromatics (20-50%) (mostly alkylbenzenes like 1,2-, 1,3-, and 1,4-xylene). Under standard conditions, there is no **chemical** reaction between these stable hydrocarbons and ethanol. It should probably be a more-or-less homogeneous mixture of these hydrocarbons and ethanol, with possibly some transient hydrogen bonding between the alcohol groups of ethanol.

However, there are some **physical** effects of the ethanol. The presence of ethanol in the gasoline allows more water (from moisture in the air) to dissolve in the gasoline. This is because the ethanol can form hydrogen bonds with water and is miscible with water. If too much water is in the tank, [phase separation will occur](https://www.boatus.com/seaworthy/SeaApr10Ethanol.pdf) leading to droplets of ethanol–water, which can cause corrosion of the gas tank and contribute to fuel line freezing, among other issues.